# Load Different Javascript Functions at 2 Different Screen Sizes

Tags: javascript, jquery, responsive-design, grid

I have a 3x3 fullscreen, responsive grid that has the height set via JS. Then when you scale down to 800px I would like for the grid to adjust to 2x3. Here's a pic of the grids at the different screen sizes:
[image]

I have my media queries set up via CSS but I also have to change the function of the div's height to take the windowHeight and divide it by 3 instead of windowHeight/2 for larger screen sizes. Here is the necessary JS:

```
(function() {
  var $serviceBox6 = $('.js-service-box6');
  var $serviceBox5 = $('.js-service-box5');
  var $serviceBox4 = $('.js-service-box4');
  var $serviceBox3 = $('.js-service-box3');
  var $serviceBox2 = $('.js-service-box2');
  var $serviceBox1 = $('.js-service-box1');

  $(document).ready(function() {
      function setHeight() {
        windowHeight = $(window).innerHeight();
        $intro.css('min-height', windowHeight);
        $about.css('min-height', windowHeight);
        $nav.css('min-height', windowHeight);
        $services.css('min-height', windowHeight);
        $contact.css('min-height', windowHeight);
        $contactLeft.css('min-height', windowHeight);
        $contactRight.css('min-height', windowHeight);
        $map.css('min-height', windowHeight);
        $serviceBox1.css('min-height', windowHeight/2);
        $serviceBox2.css('min-height', windowHeight/2);
        $serviceBox3.css('min-height', windowHeight/2);
        $serviceBox4.css('min-height', windowHeight/2);
        $serviceBox5.css('min-height', windowHeight/2);
        $serviceBox6.css('min-height', windowHeight/2);
      };
    setHeight();

    if (document.documentElement.clientWidth <= 800) {
        $(document).ready(function() {
          function setHeight() {
            windowHeight = $(window).innerHeight();
            $contactLeft.css('min-height', windowHeight/2);
            $contactRight.css('min-height', windowHeight/2);
            $map.css('min-height', windowHeight/2);
            $serviceBox1.css('min-height', windowHeight/3);
            $serviceBox2.css('min-height', windowHeight/3);
            $serviceBox3.css('min-height', windowHeight/3);
            $serviceBox4.css('min-height', windowHeight/3);
            $serviceBox5.css('min-height', windowHeight/3);
            $serviceBox6.css('min-height', windowHeight/3);
          };
          setHeight();
        });
    }

    $(window).resize(function() {
      if ($(window).width)

      setHeight();
    });
  });
})();
```

This works when I scale the screen down to 800px but if I scale it back up past 800px it doesn't revert back to the 3x3 grid unless the page is refreshed. It's the same if I start at 800px the 2x3 grid appears and then as I scale the width up the 3x3 grid appears but if I scale back down below 800px it doesn't go back to the 2x3 grid. How can I get the grid to readjust between the two grids as a user adjusts the screen width below and above 800px?

All help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: usually when i see a ton of CSS specified in JS, i wonder to myself if this is something that min-height: calc(100% / 2) can't handle...

Comment: I think this should be CSS problem, you could use Bootstrap grid system to solve it. That is much easier. http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Comment: @dandavis thanks for the help. I thought about removing the JS and switching to using CSS calculations but was afraid browser support would be lacking but after looking it appears the only browser I'd have to worry about would be IE9. If I can't get a JS solution working I may try to figure this out with CSS calculations.

Comment: @LiJunLe Thanks for the input! I actually used Foundations grid system for the coming soon page of this website and it worked great but for the final website we are reusing some code from a previous website so it's not really an option.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're setting `setHeight()` when the document is loaded. Then, whenever the width is below 800, you're changing that function to the smaller version. However, it never appears that you're ever changing it back, even when it's greater than 800. it's only ever checking that the document is below or equal to 800, and when it is it changes it. The larger version of `setHeight()` is only ever assigned to that function at the start.

so try adding this below your first if statement.

```
else if (document.documentElement.clientWidth > 800) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
      function setHeight() {
        windowHeight = $(window).innerHeight();
    $intro.css('min-height', windowHeight);
    $about.css('min-height', windowHeight);
    $nav.css('min-height', windowHeight);
    $services.css('min-height', windowHeight);
    $contact.css('min-height', windowHeight);
    $contactLeft.css('min-height', windowHeight);
    $contactRight.css('min-height', windowHeight);
    $map.css('min-height', windowHeight);
    $serviceBox1.css('min-height', windowHeight/2);
    $serviceBox2.css('min-height', windowHeight/2);
    $serviceBox3.css('min-height', windowHeight/2);
    $serviceBox4.css('min-height', windowHeight/2);
    $serviceBox5.css('min-height', windowHeight/2);
    $serviceBox6.css('min-height', windowHeight/2);
      };
      setHeight();
    });
}
```

Comment: Hi Premier and thanks for the help! I tried your solution and if I start the screen width off below 800px and scale above that it goes to the 3x3 grid as desired. However, if I go back below 800px it doesn't change back to the 2x2 grid. Also, if I start the screen width off above 800px and scale down below 800px it doesn't switch to the 2x2 grid.

Comment: Ahh, yup. I tried answering at the end of my work day and my brain was  a bit frazzled.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a problem with function nesting.  The section for <=800 should be inside the setHeight function not just in the ready function.  Then you don't need to call the setHeight function twice.

```
function setHeight() {
    windowHeight = $(window).innerHeight();
    $intro.css('min-height', windowHeight);
    $about.css('min-height', windowHeight);
    $nav.css('min-height', windowHeight);
    $services.css('min-height', windowHeight);
    $contact.css('min-height', windowHeight);
    if (document.documentElement.clientWidth <= 800) {
        $contactLeft.css('min-height', windowHeight/2);
        $contactRight.css('min-height', windowHeight/2);
        $map.css('min-height', windowHeight/2);
        $serviceBox1.css('min-height', windowHeight/3);
        $serviceBox2.css('min-height', windowHeight/3);
        $serviceBox3.css('min-height', windowHeight/3);
        $serviceBox4.css('min-height', windowHeight/3);
        $serviceBox5.css('min-height', windowHeight/3);
        $serviceBox6.css('min-height', windowHeight/3);
    } else {
        $contactLeft.css('min-height', windowHeight);
        $contactRight.css('min-height', windowHeight);
        $map.css('min-height', windowHeight);
        $serviceBox1.css('min-height', windowHeight/2);
        $serviceBox2.css('min-height', windowHeight/2);
        $serviceBox3.css('min-height', windowHeight/2);
        $serviceBox4.css('min-height', windowHeight/2);
        $serviceBox5.css('min-height', windowHeight/2);
        $serviceBox6.css('min-height', windowHeight/2);
    }
};
```

Couple other pointers: 
   You should not have multiple calls to the ready function.  You can just take that second call out and it will work the same. 
   You are defining the serviceBox variables outside the ready function so you are not guaranteeing they will have a valid value.  This will only work reliably if you put your script at the bottom of the page - and in that case you don't need the ready function in the first place.  :-)

Comment: Hi Arrowsmith and thanks for the help! I tried putting the <=800 section inside the first setHeight(); but I keep getting the following error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token if" so it's throwing off the sizing of the grid. Sorry, I'm a JS noob :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this, **note that is a TODO for you**:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $serviceBox6 = $('.js-service-box6');
    var $serviceBox5 = $('.js-service-box5');
    var $serviceBox4 = $('.js-service-box4');
    var $serviceBox3 = $('.js-service-box3');
    var $serviceBox2 = $('.js-service-box2');
    var $serviceBox1 = $('.js-service-box1');

    function setHeight() {
        var windowHeight = $(window).innerHeight();
        if (windowHeight <= 800) {
            var serviceBoxHeight = windowHeight / 3;
            var mapHeight = windowHeight / 2;
            var contactHeight = windowHeight / 2;
        } else {
            var serviceBoxHeight = windowHeight / 2;
            var mapHeight = windowHeight;
            var contactHeight = windowHeight;
        }

        // TODO modify the following height according to windowHeight
        $intro.css('min-height', windowHeight);
        $about.css('min-height', windowHeight);
        $nav.css('min-height', windowHeight);
        $services.css('min-height', windowHeight);

        $contact.css('min-height', contactHeight);
        $contactLeft.css('min-height', contactHeight);
        $contactRight.css('min-height', contactHeight);
        $map.css('min-height', mapHeight);

        $serviceBox1.css('min-height', serviceBoxHeight);
        $serviceBox2.css('min-height', serviceBoxHeight);
        $serviceBox3.css('min-height', serviceBoxHeight);
        $serviceBox4.css('min-height', serviceBoxHeight);
        $serviceBox5.css('min-height', serviceBoxHeight);
        $serviceBox6.css('min-height', serviceBoxHeight);
    };

    setHeight();
    $(window).resize(function() {
      setHeight();
    });
});
```

Besides, any concern to use `min-height` CSS? You may want to use `height` directly.

Comment: Thanks again for the help, LiJunLe! Unfortunately the above script only works at window sizes above widths of 800px. Once the window is resized below the 800px mark the height of the service boxes stay the same as they were above 800px wide. I think I'm going to take @dandavis's advice and use CSS calculations since it seems the browser support isn't nearly as bad as I thought for this. That way I can target the different widths via CSS Media Queries.